# Android images affecting each other

Tags: java, android

In my drawable folders i have my icon image, and when testing i use it as a temp picture. I added 2 other images and a XML file and when ever the app loads the imageviews with the icon set to it has different images..

this is what it is meant to be be..
[image]

but this is what it is when i add other images to the drawable folder
[image]

And no, the names of the files are not the same.
The icon is called 'icon.png' - thats what it should be
instead it is 'ic_menu_compose.png' - a completely different name.

Also the files i'm adding are called:
'buttonnormal.png'
'buttonclicked.png'
and a XML file - 'buttonselector.xml'

Even if i dont use these images any where within my app the problem still occurs.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks! :)

[EDIT]
[image]

Comment: send a screenshot of your res/drawable folder hierarchy please

Comment: How do you add the icons? Some `AdapterView` or simply add them to the layout?

Comment: In your adapter, do you check if the child view isn't null? It could be recycling an old view you dont want to. code pls?

Comment: Aha don't matter now, got it working :) Thanks any way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you building your app inbetween tests?

In eclipse:  Project > Build Automatically (ticked) (this regenerates your R file)

Are you referencing the image by a raw ID?

setImageResource(324234234); **WRONG**

setImageResource(R.drawable.blah); Right

Are you using drawable image names that are already in use by the Android system: http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/

Personally I would rename that images from "ic_menu_compose" to something like "icon_menu_compose_overwritten" just incase it is clashing and screwing up your R file.

Comment: Im building it each time.. so it generates the R file.
Im using the 'right' referencing.
And nope.. i'm not..
and I changed it, and same problem occurs, Thanks anyway (:

Comment: @Thomas Now do a Eclipse>Project > Clean also uninstall from the phone/emulator and then run it again.

Comment: NP :-) Think it would have been the naming clashing with the android os naming. Then the phone/emu tries to be clever when you redeploy and just updates certain files which it doesn't realise actually need replacing. Hence the uninstall.